# How to open a different modal that is inside of a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm using react and have a list with images, when hovered them it shows a text and when clicked it opens a modal, but each "li" has different content that goes in the modal. The problems is that every item of the list open only one modal, the last one, how can I do to open the correct modal?

Modal code

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          visible : false
      }
    }

    openModal() {
        this.setState({
            visible : true,
        });
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({
            visible : false,
        });
    }
```

list with the modal

```
<li className="bor">
      <img src={bor}/>
      <span className="first">teste</span>
      <span className="second">veja o case completo</span>
       <input type="button" onClick={() => this.openModal()} />
       <section>
        <Modal className="modal" visible={this.state.visible}       width="90%" height="90%" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() =>   this.closeModal()}>
           <div className="close">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>X</a>
            </div>
            <div>
             <h1>teste1</h1>
            </div>
          </Modal>
         </section>
                  </li>
 <li className="baz">
     <img src={baz}/>
     <span className="first">teste2</span>
     <span className="second">veja o case completo</span>
     <input type="button" onClick={() => this.openModal()} />
     <section>
       <Modal className="modal" visible={this.state.visible} width="90%" height="90%" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}>
        <div className="close">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>X</a>
         </div>
         <div>
           <h1>teste2</h1>
          </div>
        </Modal>
       </section>
   </li>
```

Comment: why do you render modal for each li? create a modal component and pass each li data as props to it.

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani I'm new to react and don't know how to do it

Comment: Can you please provide any stackblitz??

Comment: what modal are you using???

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI react-awesome-modal

Comment: could you please tell did my answer worked for you???

Comment: I couldn't make it work

Comment: could you please provide any stackblitz plz???

Answer (score 1):

As @FatemehQasemkhani said it is best practice to use single modal & pass corresponding data like below. I approaced same way & it is working fine. I am taking some dummy data inside items. Whenever user is clicking on any list(li) item I am storing that currrent clicked item inside activeItemData and passing that value in modal.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-awesome-modal";

class ProList extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         visible: false,
         activeItemData: "",
         items: [
           {
              desc: "this is item 1 "
           },
           {
              desc: "this is item 2"
           }
         ]
       };  
     }

     closeModal() {
       this.setState({
       visible: false
       });
     }


     handleCurrentItem = item => {
         // you can set two properties in setState or you can set visible property in callback also...
        this.setState(
         {
           activeItemData: item.desc,
           visible:true
         },
         // () => this.setState({ visible: true })
        )
     };

     render() { 

         return (

              <div>

                  <ul>
                     { this.state.items.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.desc} onClick={() => this.handleCurrentItem(item)}>
                           {item.desc}
                        </li>
                     ))}
                  </ul>

                 <Modal
                     className="modal"
                     visible={this.state.visible}
                     width="90%"
                     height="90%"
                     effect="fadeInUp"
                     onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}
                 >

                         <div className="close">
                             <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>
                                  X
                             </a>
                         </div>
                         <div>
                              <h1>{this.state.activeItemData}</h1>
                         </div>
                 </Modal>
              </div>

         )

     }
}
```